# How to make ScrollView automatically go back to origin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a ScrollView like this:

```
const CustomComp=React.memo(({props...})=>{
 return(<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
   {content...}
 </ScrollView>);
});
```

and when I scroll to the right and **then** re render, the x position of the Scroll stays the same

[image]

how do I get it to go back to x=0 every time it re renders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook and ScrollView's `scrollTo` method.

Here is a snack to test it: https://snack.expo.dev/@truetiem/scroll-to-top-when-re-rendered

First create a ref for scroll view.

```js
const scrollRef = useRef();

<ScrollView ref={scrollRef} horizontal>
```

And scroll to top when useEffect triggered.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0, animated: true });
});
```